# Plotting a two dimensional array using matplotlib python

Tags: python, plotting

I want to be able to plot an array of functions that are stored as a 2-d array using matplotlib. They all have the same independent variable. Specifically,

P=zerros((ntotx, ntoty),float)

x=zeros(ntotx,float)

So that the x-array is the independent variable with ntotx values, and the P-array is the set of ntoty functions of x.

I know I can break them out as individual functions, and plot them, but that makes for pretty clunky code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think this question should be moved to Stack Overflow, see [On topic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

This is a big never mind.

If you make the independent variable the first index, and make sure that the independent variable array has the same dimension as the first index, `plt.plot(x,y)`, where `y` is, say `y(n,m)`, and `x` is `x(n)`, is smart enough to plot them together.